# Is an `enum` definition inside a class shared between class instances, or copied for each instance?

Tags: c++, class, optimization, memory-management, enums

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
        enum ErrorCodes
        {
            ERR_SUCCESS     = 1,
            ERR_READ        = 2,
            ERR_WRITE       = 3,
            // ...
            ERR_ALLOCATE    = 99,
            ERR_DELETE      = 100
        };

        ErrorCodes DoSomething();
};

MyClass::ErrorCodes MyClass::DoSomething()
{
    // ...
    return ErrorCodes::ERR_SUCCESS;
}
```

In my example code there is a very long `enum` definition which has 100 variables in it. Assuming that each variable holds 4 bytes of memory, the `enum` will be using 400 bytes of memory. What will happen once I start creating objects of this class? Will each object consume extra 400 bytes of memory because of this `enum`, or will the `enum` be shared between all of the objects of this class, so that a only fixed 400 bytes will be used regardless the number of class instances initialized?

If a 400-byte memory is to be used for each instance, what alternative approach can I use in this case?

Comment: Enums are just names for numbers - they aren't 'stored' anywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An `enum` declaration doesn't use *any* runtime memory. It's just a convenient way to use symbolic names for constants.